# Copy part of a concatenated list in an array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a set of implications like these:

`a -> b
 b -> c
 c -> d
 d -> f`

Sometimes a loop occours. For example:

`a -> b
 b -> c
 c -> d
 d -> c`

I represent these implications as concatenated list in the way that:

`a -> b
 b -> c
 c -> d
 d -> c`

`a point to b, b point to c, c point to d, d point to c.`

Let's call "i" the node of the list that contains the element where the loop starts, i want copy the first part of the list from the first element to the element i-1 to an array.

I'm using java, is it possible address this problem?

Comment: Yes it is, what did you try?

Comment: At the moment I only created the list, so any help is appreciated.
I don't need that somebody write the code for me, just a small hint about how to solve this problem.

Comment: you can probably detect the loop by storing the "seen nodes", maybe using  a string representation you can revert (for example "a-b")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little unclear about your end-game with this question. I see the following 2 parts.

Part 1. Is there a cycle?

Part 2. Where does the cycle start?

Ans to Part 1. To check if there is a cycle, put 2 pointers at the start of the list, `slow` and `fast`. The general idea,

```
while (fast != null && fast.next != null):
    fast = fast.next.next;
    slow = slow.next;
    if fast is equal to slow:
        there is a cycle
```

Ans to Part 2. If there is a cycle, where does it start? The general idea of this is move the `slow` pointer back to the start of the list. Let the `fast` pointer be where the two had met. Increment both by one step till they meet. This will be the start of the cycle. Try it out. :)

Comment: Ok, for dectect a loop I agree in the use of tortoise and hare algorithm.

I will try the part 2. Thanks :)